# HTTPGET Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

An URL without a name but it has a value, is that still consider as a query string?

For example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/house/{Id}")]
public IActionResult GetHouseById(int Id)
```

link will be:
`http://localhost:44565/api/house/1`

Is this still consider a query string?

Comment: Why don't you test it ? Put a breakpoint in your method and inspect the value if `Id` when you try that request url.

Comment: @Shyju that is not a helpful comment.  The OP isn't worried about the code working.  Rather, they don't understand the nomenclature of the above code.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is part of the path and in RESTful nomenclature is not a query string parameter.

Path variables are required components of the route and MUST be provided in order to identify the appropriate route.  Omission of the id parameter when required by a path should cause a 404 (unless another route matches `api/house`).

Query string parameters however, are optional.  They are the last part of the URI and occur after the `?` character, such as `api/house?id=1`.  In this style of URI, you might expect the endpoint to return the house that has an id of `1` if the query string parameter is provided, or all houses if it is omitted.

Finally, you would notate a querystring parameter via the `FromUri` attribute and omitting it from the path:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/house")]
public IActionResult GetHouseById([FromUri]int id)
```

Comment: Are the functions of  [FromQuery] similar to [FromUri]?